# Bicep template does not allow colon (:) in properties names

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am trying to use `resource appsettingswebsite 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01'` to configure the values in azure for my app service. Now in azure i have values like

```
FeatureFlags:featureFlag1: true
FeatureFlags:featureFlag2: false
FeatureFlags:featureFlag3: true
```

But in Bicep, I am not able to put colons in names of the properties of above resource. I tried escaping the colon character but was not successful. I tried placing the the above as json object in bicep file like

```
FeatureFlags:
{
    featureFlag1: true
    featureFlag2: false
    featureFlag3: true
}
```

But that results into error
**Status Message: The parameter properties has an invalid value. (Code: BadRequest)**

Can we put the objects in configuration of app service anyway?

Help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use quotes ([string literals](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/pull/275)):

```bicep
resource appSettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  ...
  properties: {
    'FeatureFlags:featureFlag1': true
    'FeatureFlags:featureFlag2': false
    'FeatureFlags:featureFlag3': true
  }
}
```